# Automatically marking c# classes for serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, code-generation, protocol-buffers

I want to build a visual studio plugin that automatically annotates classes for serialization. For example for the built in binary serializer I could just add `[Serializable]` to the class declaration, for WCF it could add `[DataContract]` to the class and `[DataMember]` to the members and properties (I could get `[KnownType]` information through reflection and annotate where appropriate). If using protocol buffers it could add `[ProtoContract]`, `[ProtoMember]` and `[ProtoInclude]` attributes and so on.
I am assuming that the classes we are going to use this on are safe to serialize (so no sockets or nonserializable stuff in there). What I want to know is what is the easier way to take an existent piece of code (or a binary if that's easier) and add those attributes while preserving the rest of the code intact. I am fine with the output being source code or binary.

It comes to mind the idea of a using a C# parser, parse everything find the interesting code elements, annotate them and write back the code. However that seems to be very complex given the relatively small amount of modifications I want to make to the code. Is there an easier way to do so?

Comment: Did you ever implement this? I need something like this pretty badly.

Comment: Partially. In the end it wasn't so automagic as I would have liked it to be, but did the trick. I used the T4 templates of Visual Studio to define templates of how the resulting annotated class would look like and I filled in the blanks using reflection. For the particular type of classes I was using it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio already has an [API for discovering and emitting code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228763%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which you might take a look at.  It's not exactly a joy to use but could work for this purpose.

Comment: Nice! It looks like that may work. I can find code elements from the plugin, then get EditPoints from their StartPoints, and call the insert method on those EditPoints to add the required attributes. I will try it out, and mark this as solved if it worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While such a plugin would certainly be a useful thing, I would consider rather making an add-in for a tool like ReSharper instead of VS directly. The advantage is somebody already solved the huge pile of problems you haven't even dreamed of yet and so it will be *a lot* easier to build such a specific functionality.

Comment: I have Resharper, but I didn't know that you could make your own plugins. I have been missing this. Thanks a lot. It is worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you need to have a MSBuild task similar to this one http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/. is that about right?

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty cool stuff, but it is doing something very different to what I need